# Setting batch size in a schedulable class run from dev console

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have the following schedulable class:

```
global class OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler implements Schedulable {

    private static BusinessHours bh;

    private static BusinessHours returnBusinessHours() {
        if(bh == null) {
            bh = LibCommonFunctions.getBusinessHours();
        }
        return bh;
    }
  
    global static String scheduleIt() {
        datetime nextScheduleTime = system.now().addMinutes(15);
        integer minute = nextScheduleTime.minute();
        integer second = nextScheduleTime.second ();
        integer hour = nextScheduleTime.hour();
        integer year = nextScheduleTime.year(); 
        integer month = nextScheduleTime.month(); 
        integer day = nextScheduleTime.day();
        string cronvalue = second + ' ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' + year;
        string jobName = 'Self Rescheduling Order Approval Deadline Scheduler ' + nextScheduleTime.format('hh:mm');
 
        OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler scheduler = new OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler();
        return system.schedule(jobName, cronvalue, scheduler);
    }
  
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        bh = returnBusinessHours();
        Map<Id, Order_Approvals__c> recordsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Order_Approvals__c>();
        for(Order_Approvals__c oa : [select Approval_Deadline__c, Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c from Order_Approvals__c where Response__c = NULL]) {
            if(oa.Approval_Deadline__c != null) {        
                if(system.now() >= oa.Approval_Deadline__c) {  
                    if(oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c == null) oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c = 0;
                    oa.Approval_Deadline__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, oa.Approval_Deadline__c, 32400000);
                    oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c = oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c + 1;
                    recordsToUpdate.put(oa.Id, oa);
                }
        }
    }
    if(!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty() && recordsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        List<Database.Saveresult> results = Database.update(recordsToUpdate.values(), false);
        for(Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
            if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    // process any errors here 
                    system.debug(err.getMessage());
                    system.debug(err.getStatusCode());
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
    try { 
        system.abortJob(sc.getTriggerId()); 
    } 
    catch (exception e) {
        system.debug('************ schedule job exception while aborting: ' + e);
    }
    system.debug('************* schedule job executing'); 
    scheduleIt();
  }
  
}
```

From dev console, I can schedule the job: `OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler.scheduleIt();`

I need to reduce the default batch size down to a smaller batch size number. I am not calling the executeBatch method that has the batch size parameter. How can I implement a smaller batch size within the code or when I execute the job from dev console?

Comment: I don't see any batch calls in there. the `execute` method just runs at the appointed time. What seems to be the problem you're facing that makes you want to reduce the batch?

Comment: `if(!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty() && recordsToUpdate.size() > 0) {` -- that's super-overkill. You don't need either of these checks, as it is legal to DML on an empty list, and the DML methods automatically perform a similar check anyways. And, as Sebastian says, you can't change the batch size, as there's no batch here. You'd need to reconstruct the code as a batchable to take advantage of chunking with batch sizes.

Comment: There is a recursive `scheduleIt()` call at the end of the `execute()`. When you say "batch size", did you mean changing the frequency of the chained schedules? Then, is it a matter of exposing that 15 minutes as a static variable or an input parameter? `datetime nextScheduleTime = system.now().addMinutes(15);`